# How can I format output of shell command

Tags: shell, top, pidof

I combine `top` and `pidof` command:

```
top -p $(pidof <process_name>)
```

If `pidof <process_name>` return one id `top` command works. But if `pidof <process_name>` more than one ids `top` command does not work.

`pidof` returns ids with one space between them like : `123 124 125`

If I can get these ids with comma like `123, 124, 125` `top` command will work. How can I change output format of `pidof`?

I know `awk` was used for formatting text data. But I can not find how can I use `awk` for result of shell command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one:

```
top -p "$(pidof <process_name> | awk 'OFS="," { $1 = $1; print; }')"
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `bash`:

```
top -p "$(pname="$(pidof <process_name>)"; echo "${pname// /,}")"
```

Using `tr`:

```
top -p "$(pidof <process_name> | tr ' ' ',')"
```

Using `sed`:

```
top -p "$(pidof <process_name> | sed 's/ /,/g')"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one using `awk`:

```
top -p $(pidof <process_name>|awk '{gsub(/ /, ","); print }')
```